# Поиск списка в списке по условию

Tags: c#, .net, linq

У меня есть список matrix. Каждый элемента списка содержит несколько списков Items.  Мне необходимо сделать поиск нужного списка Items по условию: найти список, в котором все три элемента будут соответствовать заданным. Например надо найти список Item, в котором будут содержаться элементы где Status = Approve и ApproveWithCondition и Approve. Где Status = Approve и Reject и Reject. Как это можно реализовать с помощью Linq?

```
public class Item
{
    public string Status;
}
```

Коллекция

```
var matrix = new List<List<Item>>()
{
    new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item(){ Status = "Approve"},
        new Item(){ Status = "Approve"},
        new Item(){ Status = "Approve"}
    },
    new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item(){ Status = "Approve"},
        new Item(){ Status = "ApproveWithCondition"},
        new Item(){ Status = "Approve"}
    },
        new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item(){ Status = "Reject"},
        new Item(){ Status = "Reject"},
        new Item(){ Status = "Reject"}
    },
    new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item(){ Status = "Approve"},
        new Item(){ Status = "Reject"},
        new Item(){ Status = "Reject"}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Все Approve:

```
var result = matrix.Where(e => e.All(i => i.Status == "Approve"));
```

Все Approve/ApproveWithCondition

```
var result = matrix.Where(e => e.All(i => i.Status == "Approve" || i.Status == "ApproveWithCondition"));
```

Comment: Работает, но только для списков в которых все элементы одинаковые.

Comment: ну так добавьте условия через ||

Comment: @AndreySherman я по части linq идею дал, там уж под свои нужды подрекатировать можно)

Comment: @AndreySherman можно вообще массив с значениями передавать и проверять содержится ли в нём Status.